# learning Django+Vite+Vue

Tags: django, vue.js, vite

Today, I have some reflections on learning Django+Vite+Vue.
At first, I didn't understand why there were templates in Django but they weren't needed. Later on, I gradually understood that it was possible to simply use view and route as the backend and use Ajax and other technologies to obtain data. However, I didn't understand why I needed to use the django-vite package to merge the Vue project with Django. What were the advantages of this approach. Can't we directly obtain the data in the Vue project by visiting the website

Comment: Do you mean to fetch data directly from frontend Vue project?

Comment: What I mean is to directly use Ajax to obtain data in Vue's project, so there is no need for Django-vite. Isn't that the same.

Comment: Yes you're right.